# Can I have some help on a Calc. Optimization Problem?

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, optimization

A standard $8.5$ inches by $11$ inches piece of paper is folded so that one corner touches the opposite long side and the crease runs from the adjacent short side to the other long side, as shown in the picture below. What is the minimum length of the crease?

[image: picture here]

So I know this problem involves a lot of Calculus and Optimization, but I'm really lost to be completely honest. Any help or hints would be super helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit the picture highlighting exactly what part is the crease?

Comment: @Aaron Quitta the grey part of the paper is the folded crease. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: The modeling seems to be my main problem, I'll get back to you once I've done that.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Figure]

As you can see in the figure above, $AC$ is the crease you are looking for. By superimposing, we observe that triangles $ACD $ and $ACB$ are congruent. Therefore 
 let $\angle DAC = \angle BAC = \alpha$.

Let $AB  = y , BC = x$

Then we have $x = y \tan \alpha\quad$(see triangle $ABC$)

and $ \quad y \sin 2\alpha = EB = 8.5$

Note that $y$ will vary continuously from $11$ inches to the lower limit of $y = 8.5.$

We want to minimise crease $AC$, i.e. to minimise $x^2 + y^2 = y^2(\tan^2 \alpha + 1) = \big(\frac{8.5}{\sin 2 \alpha}\big)^2\big( \tan^2 \alpha + 1 \big)$, which is a function of $\alpha$.

I hope you can proceed now using calculus to find minima.

You have to minimise $\dfrac{1}{\sin^2 2 \alpha \cos^2 \alpha} =\bigg({\dfrac{2}{\cos 2 \alpha + 1}}\bigg)\bigg(\dfrac{1}{1-\cos^2 2 \alpha}\bigg) = \bigg(\dfrac{2}{(1-t^2)(1+t)}\bigg) = \bigg(\dfrac{2}{(1-t)(1+t)^2}\bigg) ... (1)$,

where $t = \cos 2 \alpha$.

Note that $t$ can't be $1$ as $\alpha \neq 0 $, so expression is well defined.

I leave it as an exercise to prove that this has minima at $t = \frac{1}{3}$, and minima of above expression $(1)$ is $\approx 1.687$.

Thus the final answer is  $\big(8.5^2 \times 1.687\big)^{0.5} \approx 11.04 $ inches.

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0whkiqjexw) is a graph of the function to verify the minima.

Comment: I think I do... it requires using the second derivative, am I correct? What exactly do I need to do in order to find the minima? Thank you for your help thus far!

Comment: Sorry for not I coming up with an answer for you I got distracted. Wherever the second derivative is equal to zero a minuim is also located.

Comment: @mathperson1234 I have now added the complete solution

Comment: @ab123 In line 3, $y\,\sin\alpha \ne BC \ne x$. The right angle must be CDA. Your arithmetic is correct, but the set up should be $x^2+y^2=\frac{y^2}{\cos^2\alpha}$ Now go thru similar techniques and you will get a different answer.

Comment: @Narlin Thanks, I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Since $a^{2}+b^{2}=crease^{2}$ we can minimize $a^{2}+b^{2}$ rather than its square root. Using the Lagrange multiplier method, $a^{2}+b^{2}$ will be the expression. From the lower right triangle, we can see that $c^{2}+(8.5-b)^{2}=b^{2}.$ That equation can be a constraint, but we added a variable (variable c) and we must have a constraint for every variable after the first one. So we need another constraint. Looking at the left edge, we can see that there is a right triangle with $8.5$ as one edge (dotted green) and $11-(11-a)-c$ as the base. So a second constraint can be $(a-c)^{2}+8.5^{2}=a^{2}.$

$$\mathscr{L}(a,b,c,\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2})=a^{2}+b^{2}-\lambda_{1}(c^{2}+(8.5-b)^{2}-b^{2})-\lambda_{2}\left((a-c)^{2}+8.5^2-a^{2}\right)$$

$$\nabla\mathscr{L}=\left(\begin{array}{c} 2\;c\;\lambda_{2}+2a\\ 2\;b+17\;\lambda_{1}\\ -2\;c\;\lambda_{1}+2\;\lambda_{2}\;\left(a-c\right)\\ b^2-c^2-\left(-b+\frac{17}{2}\right)^2\\ 2ac-c^2-\frac{289}{4} \end{array}\right)=\mathbf{0}$$

Solve these simultaneously and keep the positive values for $a$ and $b.$ $a=51\sqrt{2}/8$ and $b=51/8.$ Therefore, $$Crease= \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\approx 11.0418$$